# Нужно написать статическую рекурсивную функцию, которая принимает массив целых чисел, начальный индекс и значение

Tags: java, рекурсия

Нужно написать `статическую рекурсивную функцию`, которая принимает массив целых чисел, начальный индекс и значение; функция возвращает (но не выводит!) количество вхождений этого значения в части массива, начиная с заданного индекса.
Не используя статические поля, циклы или дополнительные массивы / коллекции / строки.

```
public class Recursv {
   static int count(int[] arr, int from, int what) {
       // ...
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] a = {2,3,2,4,3,1,6,3,2,3};
       System.out.println("2 -> " + count(a,0,2));
       System.out.println("3 -> " + count(a,0,3));
   }
}
```

```
Должен напечатать:
    2 -> 3
    3 -> 4
```

Comment: Для достаточно большого входного массива рекурсия может вызвать переполнение стека.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int count(int[] arr, int from, int what) {
   int v = arr[from] == what ? 1 : 0;
   if (from == arr.length - 1)
       return v;
   else return v + count(arr, from + 1, what);
}
```

Comment: спасибо,выручили)